# Is there a way to save a new column based on several conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

My problem is that I want to create a new column based on two conditions: if type == condition, and name == depression. It is necessary that two conditions like these are satisfied at the same time.

Here is the demonstration data:

```
#for demonstration
import pandas as pd

example = {
"ID": [1, 2,3, 4, 5],
"type": ["condition", "temperature", "condition", "condition", "status"],
"name":  ["depression", "high", "fatigue", "depression", "positive"],
}

#load into df:
example = pd.DataFrame(example)

print(example)
```

The result I expect to get look like this:

```
#for demonstration
import pandas as pd

result = {
"ID": [1, 2,3, 4, 5],
"type": ["condition", "temperature", "condition", "condition", "status"],
"name":  ["depression", "high", "fatigue", "depression", "positive"],
"depression":["yes", "no","no","yes", "no"]
}

#load into df:
result = pd.DataFrame(result)

print(result)
```

The most closest to the solution what I've tried was this:

```
example["depression"]= example[example.type=="condition"].name == "depression"
```

and as output it gives

[image]

But this is not what I want, because it classify others as NAN, and gives True or False as values. What I want is in the result df above.

Could you please help me to find out how to deal with it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to do that:

```py
example["depression"] = np.where(example.type.eq("condition") & example.name.eq("depression"), "yes", "no")

print(example)
-------------------------------------------------------
    ID  type        name        depression
0   1   condition   depression  yes
1   2   temperature high        no
2   3   condition   fatigue     yes
3   4   condition   depression  yes
4   5   status      positive    no
-------------------------------------------------------
```

It returns you the second argument ('yes') for all True conditions and the third argument ('no') else. The conditions are specified in the first argument.